# Creating and adding a new node to a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

It is difficult to understand how this node is being created, Can you please write step-wise what this set of code is actually doing, and what actions they represent?

```
void list::create_node(int value)       
{
    struct node *temp;// Please write in words the meaning of this statement  
    temp = new(struct node);// is this a dynamic node? )    
    temp->info = value;// is this value being assigned to this node?

    if (last == NULL)// what is this set of code testing??
    {    
        last = temp;//  who is this last; the node which has been created?    
        temp->next = last;  // is the node pointing to itself being only one node?
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next = last->next;((( // What is this statement saying?   
        last->next = temp;//  What is this statement saying?   
        last = temp;// What is this statement saying?
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you understand at least one line of this code.  Please identify exactly what you don't understand.

Comment: I have posted my doubts next to codes. the if statement WHat part of node is "LAST"

Comment: This code is already almost in Plain English.

Answer (score 2):

```
void list::create_node(int value)       
{
```

The above line declares a function that creates a node with the given value and inserts the node into the list.  The code must be examined to see where the new node is inserted.

```
struct node *temp;
```

Declares a pointer to a node.  The memory has not been allocated yet, only a pointer that will be used later.

```
temp = new(struct node);
```

Allocates memory for a node from the dynamic (runtime) memory area (a.k.a. heap). Calls the constructor of the `node` structure to initialize the memory, if a constructor exists.

The pointer `temp` is now pointing to the `node` object.

```
temp->info = value;
```

This assigns the `value` to the data field, `info`.  Need the declaration of `struct node` in order to confirm this guess.

```
if (last == NULL)
{
```

Assuming that `last` is a pointer and points to the last node, this check is looking for an empty list.  Common implementation is to have pointer values set to null to mark the end of the list.

```
    last = temp;   
    temp->next = last; 
}
```

The above code inserts the new `node` as the last node.  The `last` pointer allows fast access to the end of the list.  This allows for reverse iteration without having to traverse all the links to find the last node.

Some implementations set the `next` field to null to indicate the end of the list, others like this one, make it point to the last node.

```
else
{
    temp->next = last->next;
```

At this point, the list is not empty.
The new node is made to point to the same node that the last node points to.
This is best understood by drawing the node boxes and arrows pointing to the nodes.

```
    last->next = temp;
```

Updating the last node to point to itself.  See the above section.

```
    last = temp;
```

Updating the pointer to the last (end of list) node to point to the new node.
    }
}

I suggest you draw the linked list and walk through this algorithm a couple of times to see how it works.  Also review the *singly linked list* data type.

The circular reference of the last node may be confusing to you.  This may not be the standard implementation that most books describe, but it is valid.

Comment: It has made the picture clear to a great extent, I was not grasping the codes picture but now it is much better , I will draw pictures and write this Algo